# Замена цикла FOR на FOR OF

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, в чем ошибка моего решения?

Необходимо цикл `FOR` переписать на цикл `FOR OF`.

**Задание:**

```
function calculateTotalPrice(order) {
       let total = 0;

       for (let i = 0; i < order.length; i += 1) {
              total += order[i];
       }

       return total;
}
```

**Мое решение**

```
function calculateTotalPrice(order) {
       let total = 0;

       for (const order of orders) {
              total += order;
       }

       return total;
}
```

Comment: вот так надо `calculateTotalPrice(orders)`  ты же массив передаёшь... в for of  второй аргумент как раз будет массив а первый каждый элемент на итерации.........в итоге ты сейчас не пробегаешься ни по какому массиву....

Comment: не поняла((( как правильно прописать в коде?

Comment: вот так надо calculateTotalPrice(orders)

Comment: Спасибо, приняла, плучилось